# Vote counts will not display in /Tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, vote-count

Looking over flagged questions or answers in the /Tools page, I am occasionally curious about the up- and down-vote counts. Clicking on the vote total, however, does not have its usual effect of displaying the counts -- nothing changes, *no matter how many times I click on it*.

[image]

Comment: I am happy these bugs are popping up ... it means you are using the feature :) will fix

Comment: @waffles: Just made 10k last week -- the only thing stopping me from spending all my time there is the limited number of close votes and flags. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Admit it: you want to be a moderator!

Comment: @Bavarious: Moderator, or vigilante? /grim-batman-face

Comment: Josh ‘Batman’ Caswell. I’d vote for him.

Comment: +1 for freehand "why clicky no worky?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this out after [waffles's answer indicating deployment of a fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111450/no-vote-count-when-reviewing/111469#111469) in this question's sibling and it does indeed work now. Thanks, waffles!