# No +/- vote count when /review'ing

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, flags, vote-count

In [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) it appears that users (with enough rep) are unable to see the +/- vote count when reviewing a question or answer.  I feel that the vote count is important to know especially when reviewing older posts and should be made accessible on this page.

[image: review screenshot]

---

I was also wondering if anyone could tell me why some Q/A's have the option to *flag* and others dont?  If I go to the actual question page, I can flag/voteToClose the question/answer there, so what determines if that link shows up on the review page?

Comment: That's funny -- I reported [the same problem on the 10k Tools page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111340/vote-counts-will-not-display-in-tools), ***but*** I checked whether I could display them in /review, and it works fine _there_.

Comment: No, I take that back -- it doesn't work in /review either. Could've sworn it did yesterday, but maybe I was just tired.

Comment: It is a bug ... will fix

Comment: also ... I am leaning towards removing the "quick flag" option ... context is critical when flagging

Comment: @waffles: Yes, the only case where it's even _possibly_ useful is when the entire post is visible unexpanded.

Comment: @JoshCaswell in that case the comments may still contain extra content

Comment: @waffles I agree that the "flag" option should only show up after clicking "review answer".  I dont think anyone should flag a post without looking at the entire post first.

Comment: @waffles: Quite true.

Comment: No freehand circles? Sniffle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made 2 changes:

1. I now bind the +- split in the various inline expansions.
2. I removed the "easy" flag option, I want people to "review" stuff, early flagging skips the review process.

Comment: yes ... next build

Comment: Looks nice, ty w.

Answer (score 3):

My suspicion is that it is not a bug. In fact, I almost feel that shouldn't have the current score at all. You should be judging the post based on the merits of the post, not on its score or what other people thought of it.

Unfortunately, regarding the flag appearing or disappearing, that may or may not be a bug, but I don't have an answer for that...

As a side note, the image is hard to read without freehand circles. Just sayin'

Comment: "the image is hard to read without freehand circles" - I'm not sure I understand.  Is this a serious tip about not annotating screenshots or sarcasm? :)

Comment: @chown [Welcome to Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).

Comment: I'm aware of the "inside" joke about freehand drawings on images, but I was concerned that the image quality was lacking.  Maybe lay the sarcasm on a bit thicker next time ).