# View vote count during review

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review

I know this has been asked a couple times, and Waffles seems to [indicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111450/no-vote-count-when-reviewing) that he fixed it; however, I can't view the vote counts when reviewing. I noticed this when I came accross a fairly poor question with two upvotes, so I was trying to see if it had downvotes in case I was missing something, since I was going to downvote it (it actually did have downvotes like I would've guessed). So did I misunderstand Waffle's answer, or is it still a bug?

Comment: reproduced, fix incoming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only posts which have up & down vote buttons enabled (late answers, first posts) will support vote count fetching - after build rev `2014.3.11.2042` on meta and `2014.3.11.1445` on sites.