# Votes vs Score in review queue

Tags: bug, review, wording, score

The review queue gives the reviewer an indication of the post quality by means of the post *votes* (3 in this case):

[image]

However, this is actually the post *score* (6 up-votes minus 3 down-votes = 3 score):

[image]

Can we change this to *score* rather than *votes*?

Comment: Or at least make it clickable to expand the counts.

Comment: @Undo: Great addition.

Comment: What Undo said kinda sorta was implemented, [m0sa's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225053/237685) touches on it. It's only shown in late answers and first posts... might want to expand that to all queues?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually/375180#comment1250098_375181

Comment: Until March 23, 2021 feedback on [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/282094) was being accepted there, but this request was status-denied: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361393/282094 and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues/361393#comment1203004_360310