# Replace "votes" with "score"?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, wording, homepage

I noticed that on all SE sites (meta sites included) there is a word issue in the meta information about the questions.

More specifically, the term "votes" appears everywhere:

[image: question meta information]

How can the number of votes be a negative number ? Also, if a question receives 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes, in the list it will say "0 votes", which is clearly incorrect.

So the term "votes" seems a bit wrong in this case. I think that "score" fits a lot a lot better.

What do you guys (and girls) think ?

PS: I douby it actually bothers anyone, but I think it can be a little confusing for newcomers in some situations.

Comment: Related: [Votes vs Score in review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229608/255554)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sorry, didn't see it / find it :( .

Comment: There is no need to be sorry. (It’s not a duplicate after all.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft that one isn't, but I found the exact dupe.