# Can't view vote counts in the 10k queue

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools, vote-count, flag-queue

I just noticed that in the [meta flag queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), I can't view up/downvote counts after clicking the number.

[image]

It looks like this has been [borked and fixed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111340/vote-counts-will-not-display-in-tools). Plz fixy?

Comment: Reproduced on other sites as well, not only Meta. :(

Comment: AU has the same behaviour... maybe not a bug?

Comment: @Braiam Well... if it's intended, I want it changed :P

Comment: Same thing on SO, no vote counts are available in the 10k flag queue.